# Why TypeError: an integer is required when using cffi?

Tags: python, cffi

I'm using cffi and I'm getting a strange error. My function takes a byte array and decrypts it and creates a human-readable string from it.

```
buffer = [b'\x02', b'+', .... and more]
c_string = ffi.new("char[]", 64)
clib.decode_my_string(buffer, len(buffer), c_string, len(c_string))
print(c_string)
```

What expect to see is an english string.  Python says:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Here's how these things are defined:

```
print(clib.decode_my_string)
print(c_string)
print(buffer)
print(len(c_string))
print(len(buffer))
```

shows:

```
<cdata 'uint8_t(*)(uint8_t *, uint8_t, char *, uint16_t)' 0x7f6965aa7a50>
<cdata 'char[]' owning 64 bytes>
[b'\x02', b'+', .... and more]
64
13
```

From the prints, we can see that the function has two integers involved.  An 8-bit int and a 16-bit int.  Am I doing something wrong with those parameters?

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/myproject/utilitieslib/tests/test_mymodule.py", line 187, in test_decode_my_string
    x = mymodule.decode_my_string(response)
  File "/home/me/myproject/utilitieslib/mymodule.py", line 242, in decode_my_string
    clib.decode_my_string(buffer, len(buffer), c_string, len(c_string))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: Print `len(c_string)` and `len(buffer)` for us. Also, show us the full traceback with the line number of the error (and clarify which line that corresponds to)

Comment: Why do you have a list of `bytes` objects representing individual bytes? It sounds like you misunderstood the term "bytearray" somewhere.

Comment: Include the complete error message.

Comment: I added the len of both variables and the full traceback.